# Function definition does not work in phaser 3

Tags: function, phaser-framework

I'm an old programmer but new to phaser. Maybe my question may sound simple. The tween works in the object I defined with the code below.

```
function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('back', 'BACK.png');
}

function create () {

    let back = this.add.sprite(100, 100, 'back')
        .setInteractive().setScale(0.2);

    this.tweens.add({
        targets: back,
        x: {value: 100, duration: 1500, ease: 'Power2'},
        y: {value: 500, duration: 500, delay: 150}
    });
}
```

But I want to define it inside the function and callback. Like the following:

```
    function preload ()
    {
        this.load.image('back', 'BACK.png');
    }

    function create () {
        Gotween();
    }

    function Gotween (){
        let back = this.add.sprite(100, 100, 'back')
        .setInteractive().setScale(0.2);

    this.tweens.add({
        targets: back,
        x: {value: 100, duration: 1500, ease: 'Power2'},
        y: {value: 500, duration: 500, delay: 150}
    });
}
```

But I get the error like that:

`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sprite')".`

Is there something I don't know about Phaser? What are your suggestions?
Thanks,

I think tweens should work inside the function as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the ***issue*** is, that the `this` object in the `Gotween` function is not tied to the current *"scene"* *( the `this` object is not pointing to the `scene` ******* )*, easy solution is to pass the scene into the function, as a parameter

```
...
function create () {
    Gotween(this);         // <- pass current scene context
}
...
function Gotween (scene){  // <- parameter "scene"
    let back = scene.add.sprite(100, 100, 'back'); // <- instead of "this"

    scene.tweens.add({     // <- instead of "this"
        ... 
    });
}
```

Or a "nicer" solution, would be to add the function to the scene *(there are a few ways)*

**This is my favorit:**

1. add function to the game *config*, under the property `scene` -> `extend`

   ```
   // in the game config
   var config = {
       type: Phaser.AUTO,
       width: ...
       scene:{
           extend: {
               Gotween: Gotween // <- function added to the scene
           },
           create: create,
           ...
       }
   };
   ....
   ```
2. Use the function as a part of the scene `this.Gotween()`.
   like this you can use `this.add.sprite(...)` and others, in your function.

   ```
   function create () {
      ...
      this.Gotween();    // <- call as "method" of the scene
      ...
   }

   ...

   function Gotween (){
      let back = this.add.sprite(100, 100, 'back'); // <- access to 'this'
      ...
   }
   ```

> ***** If you want to deep dive into the whole javascript **this/function/inheritance** topic you can checkout this link [to a mdn advanced tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)